# Importing external libraries in Hopper scripts?

Tags: disassembly, python, hopper, pdb

Can external libraries be used in Hopper scripts? I'd like to add PDB support to [Hopper](http://www.hopperapp.com/) using [pdbparse](https://code.google.com/p/pdbparse/), but I haven't been able to get it to use external libraries.

Alternatively, I suppose one could just dump the debug symbol offsets to a text file and read that, but it seems like a clunkier solution (since you wouldn't be able to, e.g., auto-download symbols from the MS Symbol Server).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the moment, there is no way to debug a dylib. I know that it is a real problem, and I plan to add such a feature in a future update.

Another thing that will be added to Hopper is the ability to load multiple file in the same document, in order to disassemble things like kext for instance.

Comment: You should make it more obvious in your profile that you are Hopper's (only?) author.